# How to find the username in application launched as Administrator

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a problem today. I have a program that starts with Windows as Administrator. The probleme is I want to retreive the current UserName of the current user and getUserNameEx (NameDisplay) give me the Administrator NameDisplay...

I have also try to retreive this information by browsing Windows Logon Sessions but I have about 16 sessions each time and it'is difficult to know the good one.

Thanks you very much,
JM.

Answer (score 1):

The program launched as Administrator will still run in the user's logon session, so you can enumerate the logon sessions until you find the matching one and then obtain the user name from that.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen suggestions that you can do this using WMI - you enumerate [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instances and then call the [GetOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method to find who is the owner of 'explorer.exe'.

Not sure how well this would work in Terminal Services configurations though.  You'd also have to make sure that explorer.exe is really the system process and not some other local program that just happens to have the same EXE name.

Comment: @Nick - in that case, this problem cannot really be solved reliably, can it?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to tell who the 'owning' user is - I did a little test here: Logged into a Win2k8 terminal server with my non-admin account and launched a command prompt (cmd.exe) as my admin user.

Using Process Explorer to get details on each process, I could see the User associated with the cmd.exe process was my admin account, the Parent process was explorer.exe (PID 5008), and when I look up the User associated with PID 5008, it was my non-admin account.

If you can replicate this in your code you should be able to track down who started any given process running as your administrator account.